# CM5.3 (VI400) SimLibDeleteItem [FRN=6052,ExtRC=0] when trying to delete a document

Tags: content-management-system, ibm-midrange

I'm writing some code to delete documents from IBM Content Manager 5.3 AKA VI400. I have written a query to find an item, but am unable to delete the item that has been retrieved. I can list attributes, etc.

When I try to delete the item I get the following error:

> SimLibDeleteItem[FRN=6052,ExtRC=0]
>
> SimLibDeleteItem
>   FRN=6052
>   ExtRC=0

How can I get past the error?

```
CMBQueryService queryService = connection.getQueryService();
CMBSearchResults searchResults = new CMBSearchResults();
searchResults.setConnection(connection);
CMBDataManagement dataManagement = connection.getDataManagement();

String queryString = createQueryString(entity, condition);
short queryType = CMBBaseConstant.CMB_QS_TYPE_PARAMETRIC;
queryService.setQueryString(queryString, queryType);
queryService.setAsynchSearch(false);
queryService.runQuery();
searchResults.newResults(queryService.getResults());
for (CMBItem item : searchResults.getItems()) {
    dataManagement.setDataObject(item);
    //This is where the delete occurs. SimLibDeleteItem[FRN=6052,ExtRC=0]  happens when this is called.
    dataManagement.deleteItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When looked up further SimLibDeleteItem FRN=6052 ExtRC=0 indicated a semaphore error. This did not make sense after going and logging in with the same id to access the system via the win client it was apparent that the id did not have access to the delete process.

**In Summary**

1. Cause: The ID being used for delete did not have access to delete.
2. Diagnosis: Log into the windows client to see if the delete function can be seen.
3. Solution: Get more access for the ID doing the delete.

No coding or special configuration needed to change.